# How configure multiple Redis instances on Debian

Tags: redis, debian-based

I've got a Debian server running Redis and I'd like to run a second copy using a different port.  There are plenty of guides explaining how to do it on Ubuntu and other flavours of Linux but I'm having a hard time translating those to Debian.

So far I've created a copy of the /etc/redis/redis.conf and have renamed it /etc/redis/redis_6380.conf.  In the new file I've changed the name of the PID file, location of the log file, the listening port (to 3680) so that they do not conflict with the existing instance of Redis.

The problem I have is knowing which changes to make so that systemd can start the new instance.

I've made a duplicate of /lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service and called it redis-server-6380.service and have changed the EXECStart and PIDFile lines to point to the new files:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis_6380.conf
PIDFile=/var/run/redis/redis-server_6380.pid
```

Doing:

```
systemctl enable redis-server-6380.service
```

results in:

```
Failed to enable unit: File /etc/systemd/system/redis.service already exists and is a symlink to /lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service
```

How do I fix this ?  I'm guessing that I've missed out a vital step but I'm not that familiar with configuring systemd supervised processes on Debian.

Answer (score 1):

The end of the `redis-server` unit file would say:

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=redis.service
```

Either remove that Alias, or make sure it would be unique.

Also: make sure your Redis instances would have their own database and log files.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed the Alias line to Alias=redis.service.3680 and now get a warning that "redis-server-6380.service: PID file /var/run/redis/redis-server_6380.pid not readable (yet?) after start-post: No such file or directory"  This is despite /var/run/redis being created and also belonging to the redis group.

Comment: Check /var/log/redis. Last time I've seen that error, my permissions were wrong on /var/lib/redis.